# Swift Calculator operator issue

Tags: ios, swift

Hello everyone and thank you for visiting my page. I'm currently learning to create a calculator for my class but notice an error occurs when I type in for example:

5 + 5 = 10 // This is correct

5 + 2 * 3 + 5 = 26 // No issue yet

5 + 2 = 7 + (Will add the last operator with the number. Meaning the screen will show 9 before I can pick a number to add.)

Any advice in how I should be thinking in order to solve this problem would be appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    enum Operation: String {
        case Divide = "/"
        case Multiple = "*"
        case Subtract = "-"
        case Add = "+"
        case Empty = "Empty"
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var outputLbl: UILabel!

    // This is initialized once the app loads. 

    var btnSound: AVAudioPlayer!

    var runningNumber = ""
    var leftValStr = ""
    var rightValStr = ""
    var currentOperation: Operation = Operation.Empty
    var result = ""


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("btn", ofType: "wav")
        let soundUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

        do {
            try btnSound = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundUrl)
            btnSound.prepareToPlay()
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print(err.debugDescription)
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func numberPressed(btn: UIButton) {
        playSound()

        // Each button is assigned to a tag from 0-9. 
        // When button is pressed it is stored to btn.
        runningNumber += "\(btn.tag)"
        outputLbl.text = runningNumber
    }

    @IBAction func onDividePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        processOperation(Operation.Divide)
    }

    @IBAction func onMultiplyPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        processOperation(Operation.Multiple)
    }

    @IBAction func onSubtractPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        processOperation(Operation.Subtract)
    }

    @IBAction func onAddPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        processOperation(Operation.Add)
    }

    @IBAction func onEqualPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        processOperation(currentOperation)
    }

    @IBAction func onClearPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        clearCalcuator()
    }



    // op is what is storing the Operator. It could have been named anything
    func processOperation(op: Operation) {
        playSound()

        if currentOperation != Operation.Empty {
            // Run some math.

            // A user selected an operator, but then selected another
            // operator without first selecting a number
            if runningNumber != "" {
                rightValStr = runningNumber
                runningNumber = ""

            }

            if currentOperation == Operation.Multiple {
                result = "\(Double(leftValStr)! * Double(rightValStr)!)"
            } else if currentOperation == Operation.Divide {
                result = "\(Double(leftValStr)! / Double(rightValStr)!)"
            } else if currentOperation == Operation.Subtract {
                result = "\(Double(leftValStr)! - Double(rightValStr)!)"
            } else if currentOperation == Operation.Add {
                result = "\(Double(leftValStr)! + Double(rightValStr)!)"
            }

            leftValStr = result
            outputLbl.text = result

            currentOperation = op

        } else {
            // This is the first time an Operator has been pressed.

            leftValStr = runningNumber
            runningNumber = ""
            currentOperation = op
        }
    }

    func clearCalcuator() {
        playSound()

        if outputLbl.text != "0" {
            runningNumber = ""
            leftValStr = ""
            rightValStr = ""
            currentOperation = Operation.Empty

        }

        outputLbl.text = "0"
    }


    // Function was created to keep the code DRY. 
    // Now can use playSound() on top. Exp: Line 51
    func playSound() {
        if btnSound.playing {
            btnSound.stop()
        }

        btnSound.play()
    }
}
```

I'm still a beginner with SWIFT but hope to improve by learning from those who better understand. If you have any advice with my current code on how I can improve as well, all recommendations are happily welcomed. Thank you again.

Comment: `5 + 2 * 3 + 5 = 26` is not correct. That should be `16`.

Comment: @Rob This is for a calculator. Not programming operand precedence.

Comment: @rocky Almost all calculators will honor this operator precedence (with the exception of RPN calculators, where you do this yourself). If you don't want to honor this, that's certainly up to you, but that's extremely unconventional and will be frustrating for end-users.

Comment: The OP needs to clarify the calculator's intended behavior then.

Comment: Are you sure you want this type of calculator? Most classes would get you to do an RPN calculator because it solves this problem. And by the way 5+2*3+5=26 on a desk calculator, but =16 on the iPhone calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you describe is a result of the fact that the `@IBAction` for `=` is passing an `Operation` of `currentOperation`, which means that if that last operation was `+`, that means that the `=` button is going to behave just like hitting `+` again. That's why you see the behavior you do.

To remedy this, you need to make sure that when you press `=`, `processOperation` will set `currentOperation` to something else so that when you next call `processOperation`, no further calculation is performed. To do this, all you need to do is add one more `case` to `Operation` for `=`:

```
enum Operation: String {
    case Divide = "/"
    case Multiple = "*"
    case Subtract = "-"
    case Add = "+"
    case Equal = "="
    case Empty = "Empty"
}
```

And then change the `@IBAction` for `=` to just pass this `Operation` rather than `currentOperation`:

```
@IBAction func onEqualPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    processOperation(.Equal)
}
```

So, when you call `processOperation`, this will perform the `currentOperation`, and then when it's done, it will reset `currentOperation` to `Operation.Equal`, which the next time you do the next call to `processOperation`, it will not repeat any further calculation based upon `.Equal`.

Comment: Thank you!! for both helping me solve what I was missing and also for explaining the reason behind the error that was occurring. Now it makes better sense. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should save it to a variable that unless cleared has your next operation happen on it.

```
var answer = 5 + 2
```

display your `answer` variable in the calculator and then if another operation button is pressed then you use the answer variable e.x. + 9
would be `answer + 9` and hitting `=` would update the ui to show `16` if the user hits `clear` you just set `answer = 0`